# Flutter: checkbox and its state in the Form

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter (and programming). I don't understand why my code is not working properly, meaning I don't understand why the value and the representation are not changing. I'd appreciate any advice.

The code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   bool isChecked = false;

<Page and Form code>

Row(
  children: [
    Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = !isChecked;
          //state.didChange(value);
          print(isChecked);
        });
                   
    const Text(
      'I would like to receive newsletter and promo.',
      softWrap: true,
    ),
   ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the variable `isChecked` within the build method, when you call `setState` you tell the widget to run the build method again, so `isChecked` gets assigned to be false again.

To solve this, simply make the `isChecked` variable a class variable:

From this:

```
class _MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    bool isChecked = false;
    ...
  }
}
```

to this:

```
class _MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
...
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    ...
  }
}
```